# how to compile cmake on linux so that it can generate vsproj files?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, cmake, msbuild

I would like to generate visual studio project files on linux using cmake.

Unfortunately, the visual studio project file generator is not enabled by default on linux.

The cmake build instructions don't mention how to enable this feature on linux. It seems like the generators are enabled based on the host platform cmake is being build. Has anybody a patched cmake to enable the Visual Studio Project Generator on linux ?

We have tools that work on linux and windows for analyzing projects by parsing .sln/.vcxproj files. However generating .sln/.vcxproj files on windows is quite inconvenient as our main development is done on linux/osx.

Comment: Even if you were successful `CMake` generated projects are not that useful outside the machine that built them. They still require `CMake` and the paths that `CMake` added to the project would be wrong / nonsense.

Comment: I would concentrate on automating the Visual Studio build process on your windows test box. This should be easy to make it with little to no user intervention. I assume you have your source code in git or svn.

Comment: The paths are useful to us regardless of the machine they are generated as our main focus is dependency analysis. We have a preprocessing step that fixes up the paths.

Comment: `CMake` source code is available. You can build it using `CMake` to generate a Makefile. I am not sure how easy it is to get it to build Visual Studio support for a linux build. I have not built `CMake` in a few years.

Comment: CMakes sourcecode has a bunch of `#ifndef(_WIN32)`, looks like there is nothing inherent that would make building the vs generator on linux not possible. Someone just needs to remove the ifndefs ...

Comment: Then have to decide whether it is worthwhile to attempt to create a modified `CMake` versus automating the process of running `CMake` for your project  on windows. I still think the latter is the better solution. With that said an alternate solution is to run `CMake` under wine. I know this has worked in the past.

Comment: Abandon CMake. Its too much trouble. You will regret it in the long run.

Comment: @jww funny you say that, this is the whole goal of this project actually.
We plan to automatically convert cmake projects to https://www.buckaroo.pm

And it turned out that vcxproject output is very suitable for this conversion.
However, now I'm considering to write a custom generator for cmake

Comment: @Gaetano - Again, good luck with things. We documented the reasons we are removing CMake support from our library. You might want to take a look at [CMake Removal](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CMake#CMake_Removal). Some of them are very important to most projects.

Comment: @jww thanks your link about cmake removal is very valuable to us.
I've just noticed that someone ported your project to buckaroo. http://buckaroo.pm/project/weidai11/cryptopp

Take a look at the buck build script: https://github.com/njlr/cryptopp/blob/buck/5.6.5/BUCK

Our goal is to automatically translate cmake projects to buck.
Vsproj files just seemed to be easy to map to BUCK...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot generate Visual Studio Solutions under Linux. Nowadays you can generate Visual Studio solutions via ssh to a Windows docker container.